# Memory issue with NSMutableData

Tags: ios, objective-c, encryption, memory-leaks, automatic-ref-counting

I have converted my project to ARC. Later I found a memory leak related to PDF that I'm loading. What happen actually is Memory is not released properly once the PDF view pop from my navigation controller when i'm going back. Then I use Instrument to see what code line is responsible for this memory leaking.

In following I have explained what is happening.

First I check whether my pdf is encrypted(It is encrypted). Then I decrypt it using StringEncryption Class

```
StringEncryption *crypto = [[StringEncryption alloc]init];
self.stringEncryption = crypto;
[self.stringEncryption setDelegate:self];
NSData *encryptedPDFData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:pdfPath];
[crypto decryptUsingBGProcess:encryptedPDFData key:[key dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

decryptUsingBGProcess method is as follows

```
@autoreleasepool {{
    CCOptions padding = kCCOptionPKCS7Padding;  
    NSMutableData *decryptedData =[self doCipher:plainText key:aSymmetricKey context:kCCDecrypt padding:&padding ];
    if(!decryptedData)NSLog(@"0001 , EVT,%@, %@,Decryption failed ",[[self class] description],NSStringFromSelector(_cmd));
    if(delegate && [delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(decryptionCompleted:)]){
        if([delegate isKindOfClass:[PDFAnnotationSampleViewController class]] )
            [((PDFAnnotationSampleViewController*)delegate) performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(decryptionCompleted:) withObject:decryptedData waitUntilDone:NO];
        else [delegate decryptionCompleted:decryptedData];
    }
}
```

docyper method is as follows

```
- (NSMutableData *)doCipher:(NSData *)plainText key:(NSData *)aSymmetricKey
             context:(CCOperation)encryptOrDecrypt padding:(CCOptions *)pkcs7
{
    CCCryptorStatus ccStatus = kCCSuccess;
    // Symmetric crypto reference.
    CCCryptorRef thisEncipher = NULL;
    // Cipher Text container.
    NSMutableData * cipherOrPlainText = nil;
    // Pointer to output buffer.
    uint8_t * bufferPtr = NULL;
    // Total size of the buffer.
    size_t bufferPtrSize = 0;
    // Remaining bytes to be performed on.
    size_t remainingBytes = 0;
    // Number of bytes moved to buffer.
    size_t movedBytes = 0;
    // Length of plainText buffer.
    size_t plainTextBufferSize = 0;
    // Placeholder for total written.
    size_t totalBytesWritten = 0;
    // A friendly helper pointer.
    uint8_t * ptr;

    // Initialization vector; dummy in this case 0's.
    uint8_t iv[kChosenCipherBlockSize];
    memset((void *) iv, 0x0, (size_t) sizeof(iv));

    //NSLog(@"doCipher: plaintext: %@", plainText);
    NSLog(@"doCipher: key length: %d", [aSymmetricKey length]);

    plainTextBufferSize = [plainText length];

    //LOGGING_FACILITY(plainTextBufferSize > 0, @"Empty plaintext passed in." );

    NSLog(@"pkcs7: %d", *pkcs7);
    // We don't want to toss padding on if we don't need to
    if(encryptOrDecrypt == kCCEncrypt) {
        if(*pkcs7 != kCCOptionECBMode) {
            if((plainTextBufferSize % kChosenCipherBlockSize) == 0) {
                *pkcs7 = 0x0000;
            } else {
                *pkcs7 = kCCOptionPKCS7Padding;
            }
        }
    } else if(encryptOrDecrypt != kCCDecrypt) {
        NSLog(@"Invalid CCOperation parameter [%d] for cipher context.", *pkcs7 );
    } 

    // Create and Initialize the crypto reference.
    ccStatus = CCCryptorCreate(encryptOrDecrypt,
                               kCCAlgorithmAES128,
                               *pkcs7,
                               (const void *)[aSymmetricKey bytes],
                               kChosenCipherKeySize,
                               (const void *)iv,
                               &thisEncipher
                               );

   //LOGGING_FACILITY1( ccStatus == kCCSuccess, @"Problem creating the context, ccStatus == %d.", ccStatus );

    // Calculate byte block alignment for all calls through to and including final.
    bufferPtrSize = CCCryptorGetOutputLength(thisEncipher, plainTextBufferSize, true);

    // Allocate buffer.
    bufferPtr = malloc( bufferPtrSize * sizeof(uint8_t) );

    // Zero out buffer.
    memset((void *)bufferPtr, 0x0, bufferPtrSize);

    // Initialize some necessary book keeping.

    ptr = bufferPtr;

    // Set up initial size.
    remainingBytes = bufferPtrSize;

    // Actually perform the encryption or decryption.
    ccStatus = CCCryptorUpdate(thisEncipher,
                               (const void *) [plainText bytes],
                               plainTextBufferSize,
                               ptr,
                               remainingBytes,
                               &movedBytes
                               );

   //LOGGING_FACILITY1( ccStatus == kCCSuccess, @"Problem with CCCryptorUpdate, ccStatus == %d.", ccStatus );

    // Handle book keeping.
    ptr += movedBytes;
    remainingBytes -= movedBytes;
    totalBytesWritten += movedBytes;

    // Finalize everything to the output buffer.
    ccStatus = CCCryptorFinal(thisEncipher,
                              ptr,
                              remainingBytes,
                              &movedBytes
                              );

    totalBytesWritten += movedBytes;

    if(thisEncipher) {
        (void) CCCryptorRelease(thisEncipher);
        thisEncipher = NULL;
    }

    if (ccStatus == kCCSuccess)
        cipherOrPlainText = [NSData dataWithBytes:(const void *)bufferPtr length:(NSUInteger)totalBytesWritten];
    else
        cipherOrPlainText = nil;

    if(bufferPtr) free(bufferPtr);

    return cipherOrPlainText;

}


// this added by David
- (NSData*) md5data: ( NSString *) str
{
    const char *cStr = [str UTF8String];
    unsigned char result[CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH];
    CC_MD5( cStr, strlen(cStr), result );
    NSString* temp = [NSString  stringWithFormat:
            @"02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X",
            result[0], result[1], result[2], result[3], result[4],
            result[5], result[6], result[7],
            result[8], result[9], result[10], result[11], result[12],
            result[13], result[14], result[15]
            ];
    return  [NSData dataWithBytes:[temp UTF8String] length:[temp length]];

}
```

After decrpting it calls decryptionCompleted: method using the delegate.That method is as follows

```
-(void)decryptionCompleted:(NSData*)decryptedData{
    /* PDF has decrypted successfully */
    NSLog(@"0403 , EVT,%@, %@,Paper is Decrypted successfuly ",[[self class] description],NSStringFromSelector(_cmd));
    NSMutableData *decryptedMData = [[NSMutableData alloc] initWithData:decryptedData];
    APPDFDocument *pdfFile = [[APPDFDocument alloc] initWithPDFData:decryptedMData information:self.pdfInfo];
    self.passwordEncrypted = [pdfFile isEncrypted];
    NSLog(@"0404 , EVT,%@, %@,Paper is Decrypted paper has password encryption = %@ ",[[self class] description],NSStringFromSelector(_cmd),self.passwordEncrypted?@"YES":@"NO");
    [self loadPDF:pdfFile];
}
```

Here is the place that shows where the memory leak happens. Refer the following screen shot of profiler.

[image]

(Here I have zoom the issue area)
[image]
Can some help me to find what has gone wrong. Or else please guide me how to do further analysis

Comment: Does the static analyzer complain?

Comment: no.. its not complained.

Comment: The `loadPDF:` method is the most interesting. What does it do? (I suspect, it retains _pdfFile_, and _pdfFile_ retains  _decryptedMData_.

Comment: that method just load the pdf to the view. But it doesn't matter. Because I just add return before that method call. Then PDF doesn't load to the view. But memory issue remains same. I don't know why

Comment: An aside: How will you know at decrypt tine if padding has been added? I suggest always adding padding  unless the data is **always** a block size multiple.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
 NSMutableData *decryptedMData = [decryptedData mutableCopy];
```

And also place the auto release block inside this method too like this :

```
 -(void)decryptionCompleted:(NSData*)decryptedData{
@autoreleasepool{
        /* PDF has decrypted successfully */
        NSLog(@"0403 , EVT,%@, %@,Paper is Decrypted successfuly ",[[self class] description],NSStringFromSelector(_cmd));
        NSMutableData *decryptedMData = [[NSMutableData alloc] initWithData:decryptedData];
        APPDFDocument *pdfFile = [[APPDFDocument alloc] initWithPDFData:decryptedMData information:self.pdfInfo];
        self.passwordEncrypted = [pdfFile isEncrypted];
        NSLog(@"0404 , EVT,%@, %@,Paper is Decrypted paper has password encryption = %@ ",[[self class] description],NSStringFromSelector(_cmd),self.passwordEncrypted?@"YES":@"NO");
        [self loadPDF:pdfFile];
}
}
```

Comment: still no luck. I add the autoreleasepool block. But problem remains.

Comment: Are you getting any crash while reaching this block ? are you calling this block multiple times simultaneously?

Comment: No crashes happend. Pdf load without any issue. I'm not calling it multiple times. In the screen shot I have load the PDF twice by going back and forth. thats why it shows two memory increases.